# show years between 2 dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in excel which contains 2 dates like this:

```
01.03.2006 - 01.11.2011
```

Is it possible to write in another column the years between those 2 dates?I should get 2006,2007,2008,2009.2010,2011 . The separator between the years doesn't matter. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: My take is that the easiest way to do this would require VBA, but I'd highly suggest you give it some tries and post back specifically where you're stuck moreso that "how do you do this?

Comment: Agreed, VBA-solution will do it. This could be done with formula in google-spreadsheets, [here's example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fmIth45LO964pKdjD2SDgnROjkvvRXTwnT4CSCfWyac/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please have a look at the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically: _3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone may be able to work out this with a formula, but here's a rough VB solution:

```
Function return_Missing(ByVal firstDate As Range, ByVal lastDate As Range)
Dim i&, k&
k = 1

For i = firstDate To lastDate - 1
    return_Missing = return_Missing & firstDate + k & ", "
    k = k + 1
Next i

return_Missing = Left(Trim(return_Missing), Len(Trim(return_Missing)) - 1)

Debug.Print return_Missing
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I guess:

```
Public Function YearsBetweenDates(dateRange As String) As Variant
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim splitResult() As String
    Dim year1, year2 As Integer
    Dim result As String
    splitResult = Split(Replace(dateRange, " ", ""), "-")
    year1 = Year(CDate(splitResult(0)))
    year2 = Year(CDate(splitResult(1)))
    If year1 <= year2 Then
        result = CStr(year1)
        Do While year1 < year2
            year1 = year1 + 1
            result = result & "," & CStr(year1)
        Loop
    Else
        GoTo ErrorHandler
    End If
    YearsBetweenDates = result
    Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    YearsBetweenDates = xlErrValue
End Function
```